# How to send BNB from BSC Network to smart contract

Tags: web3js

Hello I have to send $10 to contract from BSC NETWORK

```
var toSend = web3.utils.toWei("10","ether");
MyContract.methods.UpdateUser(73104224,account).send ( { value: toSend  ,  from: account, gas : 210000 });
```

I got this code to send 10 ether, But how could I send $10 using BNB?
Is Gas parameter is correct?. Can I lower it by any other way.?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't have to give lower gas. Because, unused gas paying back to transaction owner.

If you want to send cryptocurrency in dollars, you have to use an API for it. API will get the price then you will calculate how much do you want to send.

Comment: Can you please share some code or link on how to use api and from where I will get api

Comment: I found a library for getting cryptocurrencies price. [Here it is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-price).